# Rigid body doing rotation

Tags: rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, torque

Is it possible that a rigid body is rotating but net torque about any point *in* the body is $0$? The reason behind asking this is if we apply two *unequal* like parallel forces at two ends of a uniform rod, there will be a torque produced. But the point where the resultant of the forces act on the body will experience no torque since the net force passes through that point.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is center of mass shifted due to application of force](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/726829/)

Comment: You are basically asking the same question as you did here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/726829/

Comment: Thank you @BobD for replying. Actually the previous question has been closed and there was no room for me for further discussion. That is why i had to make a new post.

Comment: But my this post differs from the previous one since i asked a different question. My query is if a body is rotating,can there be a point about which net torque will be $0$?